# PHP Validation for character ZERO"0"

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using a validator to validate user input in my Laravel 8.5x project.
This is the code I use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
$validator = Validator::make(['SelectedMonth' => $SelectedMonth, 'SelectedStartDate' => $SelectedStartDate, 'SelectedEndDate' => $SelectedEndDate], [
                    'SelectedMonth' => 'required|max:7|regex:[^(\d{4}-)?\d{2}$]',
                    'SelectedStartDate' => 'nullable|max:12|regex:/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/',
                    'SelectedEndDate' => 'nullable|max:12|regex:/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/'
                ]);
                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    abort(404);
                } else {}
```

It works great but the problem is when the user doesn't set SelectedEndDate or SelectedStartDate to anything and the value stays "0" <- ZERO. The validator doesn't take "0" as nullable so it's always false. How can I add an exception for "0" to be true?
Thanks

Comment: IMO I see that it is better to keep the date fields as a date fields and prevent it to contain anything else rather than a dates. so the `0` will not be accepted. most of the date picker components can handle this.

Comment: Can you show the HTML / template / form where the date entry happens? Zero does seem an odd default for a date picker, and maybe it can be fixed there?